# how to hide hidden directory on ftp client

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have used vsftpd to create ftp server.I am using ubuntu 12.04 desktop version.I have issue with hidden file, When I access server through FTP client its shows all the directory including hidden directory of system started with "." I have used option force_dot_files=NO in vsftpd config file but its still listing all the directories. Please guide me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put

`hide_file={.*}`

in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

From the manual:

> hide_file
>
> This option can be used to set a pattern for filenames (and directory names etc.) which should be hidden from directory listings. Despite being hidden, the files / directories etc. are fully accessible to clients who know what names to actually use. Items will be hidden if their names contain the string given by hide_file, or if they match the regular expression specified by hide_file. Note that vsftpd's regular expression matching code is a simple implementation which is a subset of full regular expression functionality. See deny_file for details of exactly what regex syntax is supported.

```
Example: hide_file={.mp3,.hidden,hide,h?}
Default: (none)
```

This will only hide the file. You can still see it or use it or edit it if you know it is there.
Have a look at `deny_file` for that.

Comment: Beware that "hide_file={.*}" will hide all files.